# Isaac Newton (actually not Newton) visited by time traveller who has confusion about human anatomy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a story I read about 1992 in an anthology; a time traveler/alien, visits Isaac Newton, to find out about Newton’s life.

The visitor is disguised as a woman dressed in period garb, but is unaware of what humans look underneath our clothing.

When circumstances lead the visitor to disrobe, it is shaped like the corsetting underneath, leading Newton to freak out and to choose to never marry.

Comment: i remember the story. i do not know if alien but rather a future human very different from contemporary humans.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to know that someone else remembers it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "[A Shape in Time](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93657)" by Anthony Boucher.

It ends

> "No, don't change back. Leave it that way. I'm curious as to the effects of -what was the word they used for it in 1880 - of a woman's *bustle*."

Not Newton though. Edwin Sullivan.

Hat tip to user [Occam Shave](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/116375/occam-shave) who commented that the story is available to read on the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/details/microcosmictales00asim/page/123/mode/1up?view=theater).

Comment: That's it! Andrew, I didn't remember any Isaac Newton in it, so might have missed it matching [my question on what probably turned out to be the same story.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272465/short-story-in-which-shapeshifting-woman-scares-man-by-shaping-herself-like-a-bu) And using the answer field for easy-link titling, here is it on page 123 of "Microcosmic Tales" on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/microcosmictales00asim/page/123/mode/1up?view=theater).

Comment: Excellent!  I must have read it in that book.

Comment: @Andrew, someone deleted your comment on my question about you having a similar more vague question. It is, and I was thrown off by Isaac Newton, but they did seem similar. And we got our story!

Comment: I guess I was thinking of Newton's known issues with women and got confused