# Isaac Newton is visited by a time traveller who tries to give him a calculator

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

[This recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262570/isaac-newton-visited-by-time-traveller-confusion-about-anatomy) about a time traveller who visits Newton reminded me of this short story, which I think I read in *Omni* in the early 1980's.

A man travels back in time, hoping to spare Isaac Newton the bother of making tedious calculations by giving him a calculator.

Unfortunately

> Newton thinks the calculator is the work of the Devil and attacks the man, who retreats to his own time. Newton abjures doing science from that moment on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This one is "Newton's Gift" by Paul Nahin from Omni, in January 1979

The story is available here [Link to scan of Omni](http://www.williamflew.com/omni4d.html)

This link has a description  [Description of the story](https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf202)

> Time traveller Wallace John Steinhope believes that he will be able to
> help his hero, Isaac Newton, avoid the tedium of computation by
> bringing him an electronic calculator that can do simple arithmetic.
> Unfortunately, Newton concludes (perhaps reasonably, given what he
> knows and what he is shown) that the calculator is a tool of Satan and
> so is not the grateful recipient that Wallace had expected. (Perhaps
> the point is this: the story serves as a kind of "myth" to explain why
> Newton, revered today for his brilliant scientific mind, turned to
> religion and superstition when he became older.)

P.S. The time traveler proved the calculator worked, by

> dividing 81918 by 123 - which equals 666

Oops.

Comment: Wow. That sounds like an exceptionally foolish story, playing the old "people in the past were stupid" game and "believers doubly so." (Newton was many things, but never stupid.)

Comment: Back in the 70s, people were foolish enough to accept claims that people in the more distant past were stupid.

Comment: @Andrew  LOL  So if we accept that statement, it must be the distant past now?

Comment: Story sounds pretty lit to me.  Superstition reigned supreme before the progress of science.

Comment: There is a similar story where a time traveler tries to teach Aristotle the scientific method, but its emphasis on ongoing doubt convinces Aristotle that science is stupid and pointless because it never leads to certainty.  Can't remember the author.

Comment: Aristotle and the Gun by deCamp

Comment: @MarkRogers You put the comment in the past tense. Superstition appears to pop up quite frequently in the present day. Confirmed by browsing a few facebook threads.

Comment: @MarkOlson: Newton did have quite a few weird ideas. He fiddled around with [alchemy and bible codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton%27s_occult_studies), among other things, and he also invested a great deal of time and effort in theology, something that we don't often associate with him today.

Comment: Should have just shown Newton the `π` button 

Comment: @MarkOlson, Newton has been described, with reasonable accuracy, as "the last of the great alchemists rather than the first of the great scientists".  For example, when he discovered that white light could be broken into a spectrum, he gave it seven colors to harmonize it with other things like the seven days of the week, the seven notes of the musical scale, and the seven celestial bodies.

Comment: To Newton’s credit, alchemy (let’s say transmutation) is only obviously foolish once you have figured out atomic theory; he didn’t have that tool. Besides, it turns out that alchemist were correct and transmutation *is* perfectly possible, it’s just that the alchemist were not trying with the correct methods (that’s why they needed more research right?) and that “making gold” turns out to be far FAR more expensive than just mining it (see nuclear fission/fusion).

Comment: @WolfieSmith *If it's on the Internet if must be true* - attributed to Abraham Lincoln